# Type 'Promise<{ email: any; }>' is not assignable to type 'Awaitable<User>'

Tags: typescript, next-auth, authorize, credential-providers

I was trying to use NextAuth to add authentication to my Next app. I couldn't solve the following problem

the problem I see is when I hover on authorize

Type '(credentials: Record<string, string>) => Promise<{ email: any; }>' is not assignable to type '(credentials: Record<string, string>, req: Pick<RequestInternal, "body" | "query" | "headers" | "method">) => Awaitable'.
Type 'Promise<{ email: any; }>' is not assignable to type 'Awaitable'.
Type 'Promise<{ email: any; }>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike'.
Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
Type '<TResult1 = { email: any; }, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: { email: any; }) => TResult1 | PromiseLike, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = User, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: User) => TResult1 | PromiseLike, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike) => PromiseLike<...>'.
Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.

````
export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            async authorize(credentials) {
            const client = await MongoClient.connect('my mongo db credentials goes here');
            const usersCollection = client.db().collection("users");
            const user = await usersCollection.findOne({
                email: credentials.email,
            });
            if (!user) {
                client.close();
                throw new Error("Invalid username or password provided");
            }
            const validPassword = await verifyPassword(
                credentials.password,
                user.password
            );
            if (!validPassword) {
                client.close();
                throw new Error("Invalid username or password provided");
            }
            client.close();
            return { email: user.email }; 
            },
        }),
    ],
});```
````

Answer (score 1):

according to next-auth typescript file, you have to put `id` field on returned object.

```
export interface DefaultUser {
  id: string
  name?: string | null
  email?: string | null
  image?: string | null
}

/**
 * The shape of the returned object in the OAuth providers' `profile` callback,
 * available in the `jwt` and `session` callbacks,
 * or the second parameter of the `session` callback, when using a database.
 *
 * [`signIn` callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#sign-in-callback) |
 * [`session` callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback) |
 * [`jwt` callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback) |
 * [`profile` OAuth provider callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers#using-a-custom-provider)
 */
export interface User extends DefaultUser {}
```